# Trying to find a pattern from a vector in an array

Tags: java

I'm learning Java and I have this exercise where I need to find a pattern from a vector in a matrix and then copy the number of the rows where the pattern is found to another vector.

I'm trying to copy each row of the matrix to another vector and then compare it with the pattern, but it only saves the first row where the pattern is found

```
package exercise;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercise {

    static final int M = 7;
    static final int N = 7;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner fEnt = null;
        Scanner fEnt1 = null;
        PrintStream fSal = null;
        double[] pattern = new double[M];
        double[][] m = new double[N][N];
        double[] aux = new double[N];
        int[] res = new int[N];
        int i, ax, j, vLon, k, z, w = 0;
        boolean found, repeated;

        System.out.print("Enter matrix filename: ");
        String nomEnt = scanner.next();
        System.out.print("Enter pattern filename: ");
        String nomEnt1 = scanner.next();
        System.out.print("Enter new filename: ");
        String nomSal = scanner.next();

        try {

            fEnt = new Scanner(new File(nomEnt));
            fEnt.useLocale(Locale.US);
            fEnt1 = new Scanner(new File(nomEnt1));
            fEnt1.useLocale(Locale.US);
            fSal = new PrintStream(new File(nomSal));

            i = 0;
            ax = 0;

            while (fEnt1.hasNext() && i < M) {
                pattern[i] = fEnt1.nextDouble();
                i++;
            }

            vLon = i;

            j = 0;
            i = 0;

            while (fEnt.hasNext() && i < N) {
                while (fEnt.hasNext() && j < N) {
                    m[i][j] = fEnt.nextDouble();
                    j++;
                }

                i++;

            }

            k = 0;

            for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                repeated = false;
                for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                    aux[j] = m[i][j];
                }

                z = 0;
                found = true;
                while (z <= N - vLon) {
                    j = 0;
                    while (j < vLon && found) {
                        if (aux[z + j] != pattern[j]) {
                            found = false;
                        }
                        j++;
                    }
                    if (found) {
                        repeated = true;
                    }
                    z++;
                }
                if (repeated) {
                    res[k] = i;
                    k++;
                }

                w = k;

            }
            if (w == 0) {
                System.out.println("The pattern wasn't found in the matrix");
            } else {

                for (i = 0; i < w; i++) {
                    fSal.print(String.valueOf(res[i]) + "\t");
                }

                fSal.println();

                System.out.println("The vector has been saved.");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e.toString());

        } finally {

            if (fEnt != null) {
                fEnt.close();
            }

            if (fSal != null) {
                fSal.close();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

For example, if it reads the matrix

```
5 2 1 2 3 4
5 3 5 1 2 3
1 2 5 2 4 6
6 7 3 5 1 2
1 2 3 6 8 4
4 5 3 2 4 6
```

Then if the pattern is `1 2 3`, it should save the following vector `1 2 5`

Comment: Please add some input data and the expected output.

Comment: `k` is an `int` and starts with 0?

Comment: Also please provide a complete code example, this does not compile.

Comment: I've just added the complete code as well as an imput example and the expected output

Comment: Package names are supposed have all lowercase characters by convention.

Comment: Have you tried writing some println's in the loops to see what the code is doing, and find where it does something that you didn't expect?

Comment: You need to declare variables `z` and `pattern`.

Comment: @OleV.V. Indeed. That was just a typo trying to translate and paste the code. Hopefully it's all fixed by now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a question of basic debugging. Therefore, TL;DR use your IDE's debugger.

Long version:

If you have an IDE, then use its debugging features. Eclipse and IntelliJ both have great debugging support and mountains of online tutorials on how to do it.

Things I found wrong while debugging your code (not everything):

1. Your matrix is only reading into the first line. 2nd, 3rd, etc. rows are all 0's. Also, you are setting N and M to 7 but they should be 6.

-- hint -- step through it and watch what happens right after you increment i, on your next entry into the loop on j. Line ~58

2. You are doing something wrong with your 'found' flag, causing your program to quit checking after it initially fails. Line ~70

-- hint -- double-check your logic here - I don't think 'found' means what you think it means in your code